# How class loader works where jvm has jars having same names but different versions, which one would be loaded at runtime or both will?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, classpath, classloader

There are two jars which have the same name which is being used in the application but for different purposes.
The name of the jar for example is "A1.jar" having different versions and used in if else condition.

```
if this:
 then A1-10.2.3jar.create()
else:
 then A1-8.18.0jar.create()
```

which in turn have different implementations of create method.

The question is when the application is loaded which jar will be instantiated during class loading time? Or depending upon condition the corresponding jar will be loaded? How can we ensure the correct jar is picked up each time.

The question is further transported to application server scenario where both libs are in WEB-INF/lib folder on jboss/wildfly. How would classloader behave there?

This happened in one of the cases for **wildfly** where had same name of jars but it was picking up the wrong one and creating an issue. But the same case was running fine on another environment..is there any order/precedence for this?

**Update**:

The classes are different when it is being called:
Say A2 and A3 class which then calls the A1 jar which are coming as a dependency from class A2 and A3 with same names but different versions.

So, this will be the case:

```
 if this:
     then A2.create()-> calls A1-10.2.3jar.respone()
    else:
     then A3.create()->calls A1-8.18.0jar.respone()
```

If this is the case can classloader load both the classes or it can be random?

Comment: If you are talking about classes with the same name, that  is not possible. A classloader only loads a class once.

Comment: Please see the updated question, if your answer still holds. There might be a way around this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, there is no specification for jee application server which version they have to use in this scenario. Therefore it's kind of (deterministic) random, which jar is used.

This really should be avoided, for example with an exclude for the deployment in a maven file or something similar for gradle.

Comment: Please see the updated question. I can avoid it using maven for one class which has the corresponding dependency but how will it resolve the methods which that class needs from its dependency?

Comment: Looks like there is no answer for this. Although, I agree this shouldn't happen, but what if its an unavoidable situation? Like in the case above?

Comment: If you really, really, really need both of the jars and you can't exclude one of them in the build process, maybe you can download the source code (if it's open source) and change the "name" of the builded jar and import that jar into your application. But i don't even know, if thats possible under a open source license.